# Should I split a single class into multiple classes to reduce dependency if possible?

Tags: object-oriented, dependencies, coupling

For example, suppose I have a class like that:

```
public class ABC{
    private Data data;
    public ABC(Data data){
        this.data=data;
    }

    public void ab(A a,B b){
        //some codes needs to use data,a,b
    }

    public void bc(B c,B c){
        //some codes needs to use data,b,c
    }
}
```

which ABC depends on A,B,C. But I found I can split it into 2 classes:

```
public class AB{
    private Data data;
    public AB(Data data){
        this.data=data;
    }

    public void ab(A a,B b){
        //some codes needs to use data,a,b
    }
}

public class BC{
    private Data data;
    public BC(Data data){
        this.data=data;
    }

    public void bc(B c,B c){
        //some codes needs to use data,b,c
    }
}
```

which AB is just depend on A,B, and BC is just depend on B,C.

But I think this approach may have a drawback: it may result in too more classes. So my question is, should I split a single class into multiple class until each class just depend on least number of other classes?

Comment: I don't know that reducing dependencies by increasing dependents solves anything. Now you have two things that depend on B where before you had one. A better question might be: "Is ABC doing too much?" That would be a more compelling reason to break it up.

Comment: Once you become aware that questions of this kind don't make sense with class names ABC, AB and BC, you will probably be half a step to an answer by yourself.

Comment: "split a single class into multiple classes" is part of [Separation_of_concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)

Answer (score 3):

### It depends on what `ABC` is supposed to do.

If you have a class that performs a lot of unrelated actions, then it may make sense to split it into multiple classes (to avoid a [God Class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object)). However, if functionality `A`, `B`, and `C` are all somehow related, then it makes more sense to keep them together. Having 3 methods inside a class is not unreasonable.

Answer (score 1):

First, keep in mind that all programming advice you will get are just guidelines, not nature laws. You can, and sometimes it makes sense, to have a global variable, even though it's not seen as a best practice. Also, some of these pieces of advice have a greater impact if you break them, and sometimes is a tradeoff in deciding what is worth breaking and what is worth following.

Coming back to your question, it is **much** more relevant to consider what is the **role** of ABC. Of course, keeping a small number of dependencies is a nice feature, and if possible, you should do it. However, if ABC stands as a **unitary entity**, then it is acceptable to sacrifice a bit and accept more dependencies. On the other hand, if ABC is doing too many things, you should consider splitting it. But only to respect the Single Responsibility Principle, not due to the high number of dependencies.